# Are there well-known Islamic theoretical works about deception in politics (or at least in war)?

Tags: political-theory, islam

After reading [this bit](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-58250607) of commentary about the recent Taliban "charm offensive":

> That's the thing with the Taliban - they're deceptive, they're charming, they know how to use the right language, but you're never quite sure whether you should believe them or not.

I wonder: are there any well-known Islamic works that have theorized about deception in politics, along the lines of [how](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1960538) Machiavelli has done in the Western culture?

N.B. there's (the concept of) [taqiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqiya), but this seem rather more limited in scope: "a precautionary dissimulation or denial of religious belief and practice in the face of persecution".

Also, even on a strictly military level, deception is pretty important in insurgency/guerilla tactics. I'm guessing the Taliban weren't quoting (each other) [from Sun Tzu](https://www.usni.org/magazines/proceedings/2017/february/deception-chinese-way-war), nor [from Ho Chi Minh](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09592318.2013.802606) advice on the matter. Are there any similar authors/sources of inspiration would be more culturally acceptable (source-wise) in an Islamic movement?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about Islam the religion, or the Islamic world in general as opposed to the Western world?

Comment: @divibisan: more generally any works that were reasonably influential, I'm not trying to get some kind of exegesis on Islamic religious texts/doctrine.

Answer (score 3):

Lying is generally prohibited in Islam (as it is in most religions). See [this article](https://quranmajeed.app/what-quran-says-about-liars/). There are (as usual) exceptions, as the last line of the article points out:

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: Lying is not permitted except in
> three cases: a mans speaking to his wife to make her happy; lying at
> times of war; and lying in order to reconcile between people.

The sense, though, is that one may only lie in the interests of a positive good: an earnest effort at pleasing, reconciling, or protecting others, not deception for one's personal advantage or aggrandizement. I'm sure this question has been hammered out within the Hadith and supplementary texts, but I only have a passing familiarity with Islamic tenets.

There is no *secular* text from within the Islamic world — that I'm aware of, at least — which would be on par with Machiavelli's "The Prince" or Sunzi's "The Art of War", both of which detail the uses of deception. But that may be a reflection of Muslim history, which seems to be comprised of a number of comparatively stable, long-lived empires and dynasties, not the warring states and bitter factions that marked European and Chinese history. A Machiavelli makes sense within the nefarious plots of the Italian Renaissance, but perhaps not so much in the convoluted intrigues of the Byzantine or Ottoman Courts.

Comment: Have you been able to track down the particular Hadith mentioned in the quote.  It seems to be a hadith narrated by Asam' bint Yazid, but I can't find locate it in the usual internet sources

Comment: @JamesK: I'll take a look later today. As I said, Islam is more of a historical/textual fact for me than something I've invested a lot of effort in, but I do have some resources that might apply.

Comment: Found it.  It is number 1939 of the Jamiʽ al-Tirmidhi  also called Sunan al-Tirmidhi.  The context is a section concerned with the maintenance of relationships, rather than the rules of war.